# Sonarcloud: Unexpected unknown at-rule "@tailwind"

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, sonarcloud

Sonarcloud is reporting a bug in my Vue 3 application due to the Tailwind settings, however it is as in the documentation.

[image: img sonarcloud]

What is the best alternative in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure this rule in SonarCloud to ignore `tailwind`

Answer (score 0):

You should configure the rules in sonarcloud.

The solution is on this page ->
https://himynameistim.com/blog/fixing-unexpected-unknown-at-rule-tailwind-in-sonar